# socket.io error on vue-cli Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function

Tags: vue.js, npm, socket.io

i've installed `socket.io` on my vue-cli project using npm.
and used it like this:

```js
import socketio from 'socket.io';
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io';

export const SocketInstance = socketio(MY_URL);

Vue.use(VueSocketIO, SocketInstance)
```

but when I run the app, I get;

> `Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function`

error on console. Without the app runs.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If I refer to the official vue-socket.io documentation, basic usage is this (for your example) :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
    connection: MY_URL,
}));
```

And, if you have to pass socket-io Instance to vue-socket.io, you have to do this :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client'

const SocketInstance = SocketIO(MY_URL);

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
    connection: SocketInstance,
}));
```

But, in that case, the package is not `socket.io` but `socket.io-client`. The problem may come from this.

EDIT :

For authentication, If I refer socket.io documentation : https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#Socket-options and the usage of vue-socket.io, this is the solutions :

Without socket-io-client :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
    connection: MY_URL,
    options: {
        // authentication options
        auth : {
            token : 'qwerty',
        }
    },
}));
```

With socket.io-client :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client'

const SocketInstance = SocketIO(MY_URL, {
    // authentication options
    auth : {
        token : 'qwerty',
    }
});

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
    connection: SocketInstance,
}));
```

Comment: thank you, but... where i can put auth headers now?

Comment: I've edited my response to add auth example according socket.io-client documentation

Comment: and... how about custom headers?

Comment: read the documentation, they have all informations in the link I share in my response